# Outlier detection and renaming as NA, using dplyr in long format

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to R programming and stuck with a problem. I want to detect and then rename outliers as "NA" in a dataset, but couldn't find a way to do it properly.
I convert my dataset with the melt function into long format
and then use the "isnt_out_tukey" function (1.5xIQR rule) from (http://www.questionflow.org/2017/12/26/combined-outlier-detection-with-dplyr-and-ruler/).

The result is a new column with logical expressions ("TRUE", "FALSE").
But what I need in this new column is to remain all non outlier values (isnt_out_tukey) and set all outliers to "NA".

The outlier elimination should be grouped by c_year, country and variable!

A second question which is more general in nature: How can I perform the outlier function on only certain variables (rows) in the "variable" column (i.e. var_01 and var_02 only) and leave the other values unchanged in the newly created column.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
library(dplyr) 
library(reshape2)

isnt_out_tukey <- function(x, k = 1.5, na.rm = TRUE) {
quar <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm)
iqr <- diff(quar)
(quar[1] - k * iqr <= x) & (x <= quar[2] + k * iqr)
}

set.seed(23)
df <- data.frame(
c_year= c("2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2015", "2014", "2014", 
"2015", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2014", "2015"),
group = c("0","0","1","0","1","0","1","1","1","1","1", "0", "1", 
"1","0","1","1"),
country = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "C", "B", "C"),
var_01 = c(rnorm(15), 2, 5),
var_02 = c(rnorm(16), 18),
var_03 = c(rnorm(15), 2.5, 10),
var_04 = c(rnorm(14), 2, 3, 6),stringsAsFactors = F)

df_long <- melt(df, id.vars = c("c_year", "group", "country"), 
variable.name = "variable", value.name = "variable_value")

df_long <- df_long %>% 
group_by(c_year, country, variable) %>%
mutate(out_removal = isnt_out_tukey(variable_value))
```

Comment: I guess you need `ifelse/replace` or `case_when` `df_long %>% group_by(c_year, country, variable) %>% mutate(new = case_when(isnt_out_tukey(variable_value)~ variable_value, TRUE ~ NA_real_))`

Comment: Thanks for your help. That solved the problem. Can I upvote your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more easy to the detection and replacement in the main df then transform it into a long format.

```
library(dplyr)
#Since you don't have outliers in the OP df, I used iris
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
         mutate(Sepal.Length=ifelse(row_number()<5, 10000, Sepal.Length)) %>%
         mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width), list(~replace(.,!isnt_out_tukey(.),NA)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The "FALSE" values are characterized as the outliers in my dataset.  I use the long format bc I have a large set of variables. Why would you prefer the wide format?

Comment: I notice that but `replace` works in the opposite way so I said if not `!` then put NA. I prefer the wide-format to  use `mutate_at` easly after that you can call melt, e.g. `iris %>% .... %>% mutate_at %>% melt`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the isnt_out_tukey function is correctly identifying the outliers you want to exclude, you could use something like:

```
df_long <- df_long %>% 
      group_by(c_year, country, variable) %>%
      mutate(good = ifelse(isnt_out_tukey(variable_value), variable_value, NA))

head(df_long,10)

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   c_year, country, variable [5]
   c_year group country variable variable_value    good
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <fct>             <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2014   0     A       var_01           0.193   0.193 
 2 2015   0     B       var_01          -0.435  -0.435 
 3 2015   1     C       var_01           0.913   0.913 
 4 2015   0     B       var_01           1.79   NA     
 5 2014   1     A       var_01           0.997   0.997 
 6 2015   0     C       var_01           1.11    1.11  
 7 2014   1     B       var_01          -0.278  -0.278 
 8 2014   1     C       var_01           1.02    1.02  
 9 2015   1     B       var_01           0.0454  0.0454
10 2014   1     C       var_01           1.58    1.58
```

In response to the second question, you could either copy over all values, then use `filter(df_long, variable == "var_01")` and make a second call to mutate with your replacement. Or you could use another ifelse statement to limit the use of the isnt_out_tukey function to the variable(s) you want.  A third (maybe less good) option would be filter before you melt your data into long format.

Comment: Great! Helped me alot! Another question to the second question: Can I create a new vector i.e.  var_out_rem <- c(var_01, var_02) and use it instead of copying all the values? Or the other way around -var_out_rem if I want to restrict those from outlier treatment?